# How add iAD banner to UISplitViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I need help!
How add iAd banner to UISplitViewController, so that the iAd banner was MasterViewController and DetailViewController at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found on apple examples the solution for this problem:

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Listings/SplitViewBanner_SplitViewBanner_AppDelegate_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198-SplitViewBanner_SplitViewBanner_AppDelegate_h-DontLinkElementID_23) you can find the SplitViewBanner example that shows how to add a ADBannerView and a UISplitViewController to another view controller.